# how to get html table in reverse order w.r.t. to keys in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I create a html  table with angular js. But getting problem to make its order reverse.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in qr_score_list ">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td>{{val}}</td>
</tr>
```

But don't know how to set its order reverse w.r.t. keys.
The condition is i cant change array sturcture.

Here is my object -:

```
$scope.qr_score_list = {'6':99,'5.5':98,'5':93,'4.5':80,'4':56,'3.5':38,'3':15,'2.5':7,'2':2,'1.5':1,'1':1,};
```

Comment: This object is not array..

Comment: than how its table genration is working ??

Comment: because you are using a special property of angular that allows you to iterate key/value pairs of an object.  It's still an object, though....

Comment: You're iterating the object keys..

Comment: Check my answer, it may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is Javascript doesn't support object keys ordering, 
You can try something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="key in Object.keys(qr_score_list).reverse() ">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td>{{qr_score_list[key]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ?

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in qr_score_list | orderBy:'$index':true">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td>{{val}}</td>
</tr>
```

this also may work :

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in qr_score_list | orderBy:'-$index':true">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td>{{val}}</td>
</tr>
```